# Dynamic routing in next.js make google doesn't index my website

Tags: next.js, google-search-console

I search on google a lot about this issue.
I'm using `React`+`Next.js V9` and `google search console` for SEO.

Google only index main page from my website.
I guess it's because it's routed dynamically.
I changed folder structure with upgrading `Next.js` to version 9 because I thought it could make easily route dynamically without working server-side and it could be index by google. However, nothing changed. Google only index main page.(index.js)

I add my code below.
If you have any idea, please give me some advice about this.
Thank you.

**Folder Structure**

```
├── _app.js
├── _document.js
├── all
│   └── [filter].js
├── category
│   └── [name].js
├── contact.js
├── index.js
├── privacy-policy.js
└── store
    └── [name].js
```

---

**Store/[name]/index.js**

```js
// ...
// This link routes specific store. It works very well, but just can't index from google

<Link href={`/store/[name]`} as={`/store/${store.name}`} passHref>
    <a><BtnSeeMenu>See Menu</BtnSeeMenu></a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Same is happening to me. I'm in the process to implement a `sitemap.xml` generator but it's not a trivial thing when you have dynamic routes. Have you already tried that? Anyway, I think Google should crawl the site and discover new pages but after more than one month [the only indexed page in mi site is the homepage](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aactionauta.com&oq=site%3A&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j69i58j69i65l3.2902j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).